# what is uri / server error

Tags: google-app-engine, uri

I have a uri / server error and I don't understand what it means.

my mapping looks like this:

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',  MainPage), ('/fizzbuzz',  FizzBuzzHandler),
                               ],
                              debug=True)

and the error log on app engine is [image: the server error log on cloud console]

Comment: Check your app logs for details

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Logs Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer). You can filter by **Log Level** == **Error** or **Critical** if you need to dig through a ton of lines.

There you can determine more about what went wrong in your requests.